# How is an image being processed to appear in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, image, image-processing

Taking help from [here](http://www.iosres.com), I know that the resolution of iPhone 6 is 1334x750 and the density or the pixels per inch is 326 ppi. So, would I be adding an image with those measures to make it appear as is or maybe even the sharpest it could on the iPhone 5?

Some cases:

1. What happens if I add an image with a resolution of 1334x750 but with a density of , say, 100?
2. What happens if I add an image with a density of 326 ppi but with a resolution of , let's say, 1900x1500?

I have picked these values at random. I know the quality of the image would be affected a lot in these cases but I'm just curious how is the image being processed to be viewed on the phone.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Feel free to edit the tags, I just added what I felt was appropriate.

Comment: PPI doesn't matter only the pixel dimensions. The PPI is used mainly for printing the image it maps that amount of pixels to an inch of paper.

Comment: so how an image of resolution 1334x750 with a density of 326ppi and another one with a resolution of 1334x750 and a density of 100ppi, there won't be any difference when they are viewed on an iPhone?

Comment: so if I have an image*

Comment: that's correct. Since displaying on the iOS screen uses abstract point system instead of inches.

Comment: the case of a different resolution still remains open :)

Comment: If your displaying a photo in an imageView and scale to fill or scale to fit then it'll get sharper and sharper the more pixel are in the image. Up to the hardware limit.

Comment: If you're creating a image using a CoreGraphics you'll need to set the image scale when creating the context. You can get the hardware's scale using the UIScreen class. Typically you'll use the mainScreen.

Comment: I'll add an answer and a demo app, because I don't know what will happen if you center the image. I believe each pixel of the image will map to a point by default but their might be a way of setting the image scale on UIImage.

Comment: I am using the image as a background to my app.. the way it would process the image in the background just made me curious

Comment: I must confess that I have not put in the kind of research I should have but I am working on it now and I will post here if I find anything useful. Hoping to find something from Apple itself